# Do I have to have the laser light enabled to benefit from the hip fire bonus?

Tags: battlefield-4

Laser lights are useful, but they tend to also give away my position.    Do I have to have my laser light enabled to gain the hip fire bonus or can I just equip it on my gun [and have it off]?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, when turning the laser sight on and off you will actually see your reticle (in normal, not hardcore modes) get smaller and bigger.

Testing this by firing at a wall ~15m away will show you what the actual difference in size the spray pattern is.